# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null?

Tags: android, bitmap, null

Here is a code that works on one device running Android 6.0 is not adequate.
Can anyone come across, tell me what to do.

```
File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
if (!f.exists()) {
    return null;
}
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
Log.d(TAG,mCurrentPhotoPath);

if (bitmap == null) {
    Log.d(TAG,"bitmap is null");
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

After the first decoding of the file, null is returned, although the file exists. I had to add an if block `(bitmap == null)` and re-decode the file. In this block, the file is decoded, the required bitmap is returned. Can anybody explain what's going on here?

Comment: can you please share your Logcat. what it showing?

Comment: D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

D/ImagesWorkerTask: /storage/emulated/0/Bliznecov/IMG_20171103_160000_1954657017.jpg

D/ImagesWorkerTask: bitmap is null

D/skia: jpeg_decoder mode 1, colorType 4, w 1728, h 2880, sample 1, bsLength 0!!

Comment: if its too big try: `BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize = 4` (for example) and see if you still getting null - pass it as second parameter to `decodeFile`

Comment: `BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize = 4` don't help me, only second decode return bitmap.

Comment: is it a static image or there is some kind of background producer / downloader / whatever and there is a chance that the first time you call `decodeFile`  the image is not ready yet?

Comment: It's result from `Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`

Comment: and you are starting decoding inside `onActivityResult`?

Comment: no, decode image in AsyncTask.

Comment: When, and from where do you start the asynctask?

Comment: Yes, i start async task from onActivityResult

Comment: 50% return null in first decode. Have any idea?)
but 
      `BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),options);
        if (bitmap != null){
            bitmap.getWidth();
        }
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());`
in second decode return Bitmap 100% times.

Comment: Yes, in Thread.sleep(3000) 50% return null

Comment: Only after Thread.sleep(5000) returns bitmap... 
I think this is a bad approach. Do you have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the bitmap would become to big for available memory decodeFile() returns null.

Try smaller pictures.

You can also rescale during load.

Comment: No your jpg file is that big. But the resolution is `w 1728, h 2880` and that will cause for a very big bitmap. You yourself can easily calculate how much memory is needed for that. Take four bytes for a pixel.

Comment: That the second try succeeds will have to do with the GC having freed some memory then.